# React.js with Redux: Get info from state

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

I'm coding the app and I can't solve a problem. I have stored user info in the state (when I open Redux DevTools I can see the state -> user: {username: name, role: ...}).

Now in some components, I want to check if logged in user is admin or a user. I have it in that state but how can I load it in some class? When I export a function, I can use `const userRole = useSelector(state => state.security.user.role_id);` but in a class it makes a problem. Can you help me?

this is my code for User class and I want to show up DELETE button, only if user is an admin:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {connect, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { deleteUser } from "../../store/actions/userActions";

class User extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();}

    onDeleteClick(id) {
        this.props.deleteUser(id);
    }



    render() {

        const { user } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className='row entry'>
                <div className='col-sm-2'>
                    <span >{user.username}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-2'>
                    <span >{user.name}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-2'>
                    <span>{user.lastname}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-2'>
                    <span>{user.tag}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-1'>
                    <span>{user.pay}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-1'>
                    <span>
                    {user.role_id}

                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-2'>
                    <Link to={`userlist/edituser:${user.id}`}>
                        <button><i className="fas fa-user-edit"></i></button>
                    </Link> | <button onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, user.id)}><i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>

                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }


}


User.propTypes = {
    deleteUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};



export default connect(
    null, { deleteUser }
)(User);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What makes it problematic?

Comment: You should use connect() of Redux for connecting your component with store Redux, did you do it ?

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

With class components, you can make use of `connect` HOC with `mapStateToProps` to access state from redux

```
class User extends Component{

    render() {

        const { user, userRole } = this.props;
        ...

    }
}



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
       useRole: state.security.user.role_id,
   }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, { deleteUser }
)(User);
```